# Increase the playground area in A-Frame

Tags: aframe

I searched everywhere and can't find the answer:

How is it possible to increase the playground area in A-Frame? (the `scene` width & height, which by default seems to be 30x30 meters)

[image: image for more clarification]

Answer (score 0):

There is no builtin way to customize this grid but you can easily do that in the console using e.g.

```
AFRAME.scenes[0].object3D.traverse( e => { if (e.type == "LineSegments") e.scale.multiplyScalar(2) } )
```

and if you want a component proper
As a script but instead using

```
AFRAME.registerComponent('larger-playground', {
  init: function () {
    this.object3D.traverse( e => { if (e.type == "LineSegments") e.scale.multiplyScalar(2) } )
  }
});
```

PS: assumed you don't have other lines in the scene.

Comment: should i add it to <head> in a <script> ?

Comment: if you want it every single time adding as a script in a component would be the safest option

Comment: i add the block of code in <script></script> to the head of the page, and the only thing happens is that the page goes white! :|